# @media selector for width smaller than 755

Tags: css

I use the following media selector which works:

```
@media
only screen and (min-width: 755px) and (orientation: landscape) { 

    p { color: green; }

}
```

But how can I target everything with a width smaller than 755?
I tried min-width 0 but that doesn't work.

Comment: Why is `only screen and (min-width: 755px) and (orientation: landscape),` in there five times?

Comment: Very good question ^ lol

Comment: lol, the answer to that is a few hours sleep and removing the pixels device ratio lol :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use max-width, which will select everything upto the maximum width of 755px

`@media (max-width: 755px) {}`

http://jsfiddle.net/a8ddg32z/

Comment: @clankill3r If that does not work then something else is causing the issue you are seeing. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPxERK

Comment: Ive added a fiddle for you to see the result @clankill3r